# How to detect printer connected with system using ionic web application

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, printing, ionic2, printjs

We are developing ionic web application with printer functionality. We used Print.js npm to print the content. If in case the printer not connected with system, I need to show some message about this. how can I determine whether the printer is connected or not. Is there any way in print.js npm or any other npm to determine this requirment.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Cordova Print Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer)?

Comment: Its not supporting web browser. I need it in browser platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Javascript alone. You would need to use ActiveX or a native application.

Ref: https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/129